# Does Bash imitate Locale-Specific Translation from C?

Tags: bash, string, c

Bash manual mentions that

> 3.1.2.5 Locale-Specific Translation
>
> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign (‘$’) will cause the
>   string to be translated according to the current locale. If the
>   current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the
>   string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

Does this way of specifying a string literal exist in C language or some C library?

Does bash imitate this way from C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$"..."` is Bash's way of accessing [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) translations. In C code it would generally be `gettext("...")` or `_("...")`. Bash uses the system's default message catalog; a C application could also load up any catalogs it wanted to use.

The `$"` syntax is a Bash extension to resemble the existing parameter expansion syntax, and I suppose particularly the [`$'` ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) it took from ksh and which [may](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249) make it into POSIX in future. The C language does not support or have a parallel for the syntax itself.